# Почему в первом случае цикл for in не суммирует значения объекта, а во втором суммирует?

Tags: javascript

Нужно посчитать значения объекта myObject с помощью цикла for in.
В первом примере  значения не суммируются, а во втором суммируются.
Почему так?

[image: значения суммируются]
[image: значения не суммируются]

Comment: 1. Код должен быть текстом, а не изображением. 2. Пройдись вручную по коду и сам поймешь, почему в первом не суммируется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом примере в начале каждой итерации вы переобъявляете переменную `sum`, в результате чего вместо суммы получаете каждое значение отдельно.